# Why is $P(X\in[a,b])=P(X\in[a,b))=P(X\in(a,b])=P(X\in(a,b))$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I saw, for any continuous random variable $X$, $P(X\in[a,b])=P(X\in[a,b))=P(X\in(a,b])=P(X\in(a,b))$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, in my textbook.
I don't quite understand why the openness/closeness of an interval doesn't matter in continuous random variable?

Is it because prob. density function $f(x)=0$ whenever $x\in\{a,b\}$

Update:
I realize some fundamental mistakes I have made after checking out the comments and answer from all of you.
PDF $f(x)=0$ whenever $x = a, b$ is so wrong. It should be, WLOG, CDF instead of PDF, $ P(X=a) = F(a) = \int_{a}^{a}f(x) = 0$, which is why the equality holds regardless of the openness of interval.

Comment: Because the probability of a point in a segment is zero.

Comment: Assuming your probability is non-atomic, the last statement is correct: Use the fact that probability is countably additive.

Comment: If your random variable has a density function $f$ these probability are $\int _a^b f(t)dt$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of "continuous random variables"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note, $P(X\in [a,b])=P(X\in [a,b))+P(X=b)=P(X\in [a,b))=P(X\in (a,b))+P(X=a)=P(X\in (a,b))$.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: This does not answer the question but may help understand more in-depth about integrals and how to calculate using probability distributions of mixed continous and discrete parts.**

For $P(X\leq x_0) \neq P(X< x_0)$ to hold, we will need to expand the concept of integral and function to allow for the integral of a point to be something else than 0. One way to do this is with [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29). The dirac $\delta$ is such a distribution defined so that for any *test-function* $g(x)$: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)g(x)dx = g(0)$$With such a mechanism we can have a function $g$ encode *"atomic"* probabilities in some set of points, use a sum of dirac delta function together with the linearity of the integral to "select" them and then add them to the ordinary density function $f$. This way we can represent a mixture of continuous probabilities and discrete jumps in probability or *atomic* probabilities.

As always we need to make sure that the sum of all probabilities equals one. In our case : that the atomic probabilities and the continuous probability equals 1:$$\sum_{\forall k}g(x_k) + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = 1$$ and we can keep using the same formalism, treating $$f(x) + g(x)\sum_{\forall k}\delta(x-x_k)$$ as our new density function.

Comment: This seems off-topic to understand the *present* question.

Comment: The probability equalities described in the question will not be true any longer if the probability density function is a distribution so it is very related to the question.

Comment: Sure, and the question is 100% about continuous random variables hence measures with a non absolutely continuous part are offtopic here (even if interesting in other situations, of course).

Comment: Yes I now see that you are right, the question did not mention anything about discrete cases. Maybe a better way to do that would have been to make a new question and link in to this one for comparison?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, for continuous distributions, the probability of a single point in a segment is zero because there are infinitely points in that segment. So, in such a case, one can add to or remove from an interval, a finite number of points without changing the probability.